# join unordered pairs of connected edges using numpy only

Tags: python, numpy

I have a concave hull (not convex) that I have the points for eg: `A,B,C,D,E`. I've gotten the pairs of points that make up the outer edges. `[A,B],[A,E],[C,D],[B,C],[E,D]`. (This is a very simplified version)

[image]

I want to get the connected points in order (CW or CCW doesn't matter) so I can use them as a contour.

But the pairs are not ordered, you can see A goes to B, then A goes to E, etc. The only solution I had was searching for each point and its next pair sequentially in a loop

Is there a way to solve this using numpy only in a vectorized manner so that its fast for a large array of edges?
I know shapely exists but I have trouble installing it and I'd prefer no external dependancies

this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
edges = np.array([['A','B'],['A','E'],['C','D'],['B','C'],['E','D']])

f = edges.ravel()
indexes = np.argsort(f)
reverse_indexes = np.argsort(indexes)

pts_idxs = [f[0]]
index = 0
for i in range(len(f)-1):
    if i%2:
        if index%2:
            index = indexes[index-1]
        else:
            index = indexes[index+1]
    else:
        if index%2:
            pts_idxs.append(f[index-1])
            index = reverse_indexes[index-1]
        else:
            pts_idxs.append(f[index+1])
            index = reverse_indexes[index+1]
print(pts_idxs)
```

output:

```
[A,B,C,D,E,A]
```

or [A,E,D,C,B,A] which is the order to follow to connect all the edges

I leverage the fact that all points appear twice in the pairs and search for their positions outside the loop. Then use some indexing tricks to jump between the pair and its next edge

Comment: Without following your logic in detail, this does not look like the kind of thing `numpy` does well.  It's too sequential in nature, going from one pair to the next.  Most `numpy` operations operate "in-parallel", working with the whole array (or along one axis), without regard to order.  Sorting is the closest you get to ordering.

Comment: are the nodes of your graph always labeled in order?   
are they always and only labels with capital letters?
Can you please add an example for the expected output of your code?

Comment: @yanziselman there is no order, and they are usually numbers that point to an index, i just used letters to simplify it and make it easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this efficiently with a dictionary:

```
edges = [
    ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'E'], ['C', 'D'],
    ['B', 'C'], ['E', 'D']
]

# make a dict showing neighbors of each node
d = {}
for a, b in edges:
    d.setdefault(a, set()).add(b)
    d.setdefault(b, set()).add(a)

# start with the first node
seq = [edges[0][0]]
for i in range(len(edges)):
    prev_one = seq[-1]
    # choose a 'random' neighbor and delete it from the set
    # (after the first step there will always be only one neighbor)
    next_one = d[prev_one].pop()
    # delete back-reference to previous neighbor
    d[next_one].remove(prev_one)
    # add the neighbor to the sequence
    seq.append(next_one)

print(seq)
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A']
```

or this might be a slightly faster version of the main loop:

```
# start with the first node
prev = edges[0][0]
seq = [prev]
while neighbors := d[prev]:
    # choose a 'random' neighbor and delete it from the set
    # (after the first step there will always be only one neighbor)
    next = neighbors.pop()
    # extend the sequence
    seq.append(next)
    # delete back-reference to previous neighbor
    d[next].remove(prev)
    # remember the most recent entry
    prev = next
```

Comment: i know i can go this route aswell, my loop does something similar. but i want to avoid loops as the edges can be in the thousands

Comment: I think you'll have to use a loop, rather than a vectorized approach. But with a dictionary, you can write a single-level loop instead of a nested loop. So the time dependence will be O(N) instead of O(N**2), and you should be able to handle long lists of edges just fine. (Still working on that dictionary-based version though.)

Comment: btw my loop is single-level, its not nested, just a few if statements. I guess if there is no different method other than my approach that can do the same but in a vectorized manner i guess ill have to give up

Comment: just tested it. it works correctly, it gives similar speed to my list implementation.

Comment: That makes sense. I should have read your code more closely before I started!

Comment: I just posted a version of the main loop that may run a little faster. Your code sorts the array a couple of times. That is pretty fast in Numpy, but it is usually a O(N log N) operation. So if you have very large arrays, you may find a lookup-based solution like this one works better.

Comment: Since it looks like there is no vectorized version. I'm accepting this answer for its proposed advantage of lookup vs sorting